# Update query using one of its fields in a select query in where clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I know it's a confusing title, but the example will show what I want to achieve:

```
UPDATE tr.tbl_to_be_updated SET cat=-1 WHERE cat NOT IN (SELECT c.id
  FROM tr.cat as c WHERE c.sh=tbl_to_be_updated.sh))
```

How can I achieve this? With this query I receive an error that it's not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl_to_be_updated 
LEFT JOIN cat ON cat.sh = tbl_to_be_updated.sh
SET tbl_to_be_updated.cat = -1 
WHERE cat.sh IS NULL
```